# Exponentiation with parentheses

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why doesn't the following always simplify to 0?

```
Simplify[a^(b c) - (a^b)^c]
```

If we `Assume` `a`,`b` and `c` are integers it works...

```
Simplify[a^(b c) - (a^b)^c, 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Integers, b \[Element] Integers, 
   c \[Element] Integers}]
```

Comment: take `a=-1`, `b=2`, `c=1/2`.

Comment: @kglr No constraints on $a$ is needed: `Simplify[a^(b c) - (a^b)^c, 
 Assumptions -> b ∈ Integers && c ∈ Integers]`yields zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For questions like these, [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) is your friend:

```
FindInstance[a^(b c) - (a^b)^c != 0, {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> 99/5 + (12 I)/5, b -> -(28/5) + (79 I)/5, c -> 61/10 + (143 I)/10}} *)
```

So at least for complex numbers, there are issues. We can try to ask for solutions with real values as well:

```
FindInstance[{
  a^(b c) - (a^b)^c != 0,
  (a | b | c) ∈ Reals
  }, {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> -(69/5), b -> -(231/10), c -> -(8/5)}} *)
```

Through experimentation, we find that `a` and `b` can even be integers:

```
FindInstance[{
  a^(b c) - (a^b)^c != 0,
  c ∈ Reals,
  (a | b) ∈ Integers
  }, {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> -1, b -> 18, c -> 8/5}} *)
```

We can guess some specific small values for `a` and `b`, which brings us essentially to the example given by @kglr in the comments:

```
FindInstance[{
  a^(b c) - (a^b)^c != 0,
  c ∈ Reals,
  (a | b) ∈ Integers,
  a == -1,
  b == 2
  }, {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> -1, b -> 2, c -> 99/5}} *)
```

Comment: $a$ need not be integer for the identity to hold. See my answer.

Comment: @yarchik I know - I just wanted to find an example that's as simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

The identity works in a more broad case of $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Verification

```
Simplify[a^(b c) - (a^b)^c, Assumptions -> b ∈ Integers && c ∈ Integers] 
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: The only assumption needed is `c ∈ Integers`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Right, because `Power[x,y]` takes the principal value of $e^{y\log(x)}$. Then the question is, why MA does not see this?